# Multiplying a list in NetLogo using reduce

Tags: netlogo, reduce

I'm trying to debug my NetLogo code,
I want to create a list from the probabilities of the neighbours and then multiply all these values in the list together using 'reduce'. As far as I can tell this is working except when it's running it gives the run-time error as below.

I also tried using 'let P reduce  [?1 * ?2]  prob-list' but it gives the same error.

Note Prob_water_water_breaking,  Prob_solute_solute_breaking are defined as 'globals' then in the setup they are assigned to specific breeds.

```
to-report all-probabilities  
    let prob-list (list ([Prob_water_water_breaking ] of turtles-on neighbors4) 
      ([Prob_solute_solute_breaking ] of turtles-on neighbors4)
     let P reduce  *  prob-list ;;this is the line that's causing the error
     report P
  end
```

This is the runt-time error:

```
* expected input to be a number but got the list [0.3 0.3 0.3] instead.
error while solute 2 running *
  called by procedure ALL-PROBABILITIES
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! I love questions involving [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce). But in your case, the problem is with the line:

```
let prob-list (list ([Prob_water_water_breaking ] of turtles-on neighbors4) 
      ([Prob_solute_solute_breaking ] of turtles-on neighbors4)
```

You (and `reduce`) are expecting a single list of numbers, but `prob-list` is actually a *list of lists* of numbers: each call to [`of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#of) produces a list, and each of these list become an item in the list you create with [`list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list).

Since you want to concatenate your lists together, you could use [`sentence`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sentence) instead of `list`:

```
let prob-list (sentence ([Prob_water_water_breaking ] of turtles-on neighbors4) 
      ([Prob_solute_solute_breaking ] of turtles-on neighbors4))
```

Another (and probably better) way to avoid the problem would be to perform the first multiplication inside the `of`:

```
let prob-list [ Prob_water_water_breaking * Prob_solute_solute_breaking ]
  of turtles-on neighbors4
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nicolas! That has fixed the problem! I really appreciate your help!